# After clicking alert message's ok button i want to focus on a input box

Tags: jquery

After clicking alert message's ok button i want to focus on a input box.

Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

```
<input class="form-control time" id="jst" type="time" name="jobStart" value="" placeholder="HH:MM AM/PM" required/>
<input class="form-control time" id="jet" type="time" name="jobEnd" placeholder="HH:MM AM/PM" value=""  required/>

        function myfunction1(){
              if($("#jet").val() < $("#jst").val())
              {
                alert("End Time is smaller");
                $("#jet").focus();
              }
            }

    $("#jet").focusout(myfunction1);
```

Comment: Please include your html code

Comment: The hacky solution would be to put the `focus()` line in a `setTimeout()` with a very short delay. A much better solution would be to not use ugly `alert()` boxes for user validation/notifications. Show them in HTML and avoid this problem.